# Calling MySql Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in my DB (mySql). But when I call it using 'CALL' it shows an error. The number of arguments is correct.

I have given the arguments and tried.

This is my sp;

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test`.`usp_select_data` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`dm`@`` PROCEDURE `usp_select_data`(
tagids varchar(2000)
,tagCount int
,_searchType int
,_firstName varchar(200)
,_lastName varchar(200)
,_postcode varchar(200)
,_email varchar(200)
,_companyId TEXT
,_town varchar(200)
,_country varchar(200)
,_sourceId int
,_biztypeId int
,_startDate datetime
,_lastcontactedinMonth datetime
,_lastcontactedinthreeMonth datetime
,_lastcontactedinsixMonth datetime
,_lastcontactedinoneYear datetime
,_lastcontactedlessthanonemonth datetime)
```

And I called in mysql as;

```
CALL usp_select_data('',0,0,'','','','','','','',0,0,'2019-04-04 00:00:00','','','','','');
```

I expect the result for my query which I explained in SP.
But error got 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1'

Comment: Does your procedure build any prepared statements?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing empty strings to datetime parameters. Use NULL instead if you do not intend to pass a value.

Comment: The `CALL` syntax is otherwise ok. The use of empty string as datetimes in procedure call should prevent procedure running at all, so looks like there is something not shown in the question causing the error.